# C Mid Point Circle Algorithm Split Circle Into 4

Tags: c, algorithm, math, geometry, trigonometry

In my program I am currently rendering circles using the Midpoint Circle Algorithm with the following code.

```
void drawcircle(int x0, int y0, int radius)
{
    int x = radius-1;
    int y = 0;
    int dx = 1;
    int dy = 1;
    int err = dx - (radius << 1);

    while (x >= y)
    {
        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 + y);
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 + x);
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 + x);
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 + y);
        putpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y);
        putpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x);
        putpixel(x0 + y, y0 - x);
        putpixel(x0 + x, y0 - y);

        if (err <= 0)
        {
            y++;
            err += dy;
            dy += 2;
        }
        if (err > 0)
        {
            x--;
            dx += 2;
            err += (-radius << 1) + dx;
        }
    }
}
```

But my question is, is it possible to have this function work the same way, but split the circle into 4 separate sections? i.e. so rather than rendering a normal circle, it would look somewhat like this

[image]

Comment: Determine the four ranges of coordinates and use `continue` statement for that range to skip `putpixel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Putting holes in circles

The implementation you had had some overlapping pixels where the 8 subsections meet. Also the circle was the wrong diameter (should always be even because radius * 2) the cause of some of the overlap.

To fix the size and remove the overlap I move half the circle out (to the right down) by one pixel and prevented half the last iteration pixels being rendered.

Also the statement `if(err <= 0)` is not needed as at that point `err` will always meet that condition. The y offset steps up 1 pixel each iteration, the `err` is to find when x needs to step.

#### Easy solution

With that the solution to your question regarding putting holes in the circle. You just need a counter to count down the number of pixels you want to skip. While that counter is > 0 don't draw any pixels.

I added it to the snippet below as a 4th argument `hole`. An `int` that is half the size of the hole at the top, bottom, left and right of the circle.

So if you want a 20 pixel hole then the last argument is 10.

See right circles in image below.

#### Limit and geek stuff

Note that the max size of hole is `sin(PI / 4) * radius` if you make it bigger, no pixels will be drawn. As a side note the number of pixel drawn (without the holes) is approx `sin(PI / 4) * radius * 8 - 4` which is almost 10% less than the circumference.

#### Solution for answer

```
void drawcircle(int x0, int y0, int radius, int hole) {
    int x = radius-1;
    int y = 0;
    int dx = 1;
    int dy = 1;
    int err = dx - (radius << 1);
    int x1 = x0 + 1;
    int y1 = x0 + 1;

    while (x >= y) {
        if(hole == 0){
            putpixel(x1 + x, y1 + y);
            putpixel(x0 - x, y0 - y);
            putpixel(x0 - y, y1 + x);
            putpixel(x1 + x, y0 - y);
            if (x > y) {
                putpixel(x1 + y, y1 + x);                
                putpixel(x0 - x, y1 + y);                
                putpixel(x0 - y, y0 - x);
                putpixel(x1 + y, y0 - x);
            }
        } else {
            hole--;
        }

        y++;
        err += dy;
        dy += 2;

        if (err > 0) {
            x--;
            dx += 2;
            err += (-radius << 1) + dx;
        }
    }
}
```

Also as I geeked out on this function as it makes some good high performance shapes like rounded cross and boxes with only very minor changes that I thought worth sharing. See image

To get other shapes...

Add back the y `err` test and then change the delta X, and delta y error change to values other than 2.

```
        if(err <= 0){  // needed
            y++;
            err += dy;
            dy += 8;  << change this
        }

        if (err > 0) {
            x--;
            dx += 8;  << change this
            err += (-radius << 1) + dx;
        }
        // See image in answer
        // 8 made bottom right cross, 
        // 18 top right
        // 28 top left
        // 0.8 bottom left
```

[image]

The image shows the shapes and the result of the holes